# Add output of loop to data frame within R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I am looking to run tests on the speed it takes to perform database queries. I am looping a query X number of times and would like to store the sys.time calculated to execute from each query in a data frame. I have tested the loops and functions, which work, but when I attempt to store the calculated sys.time into the data frame is get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, query_time, value = 0.359616041183472) : replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

I am unsure of what my issue is, any help is appreciated. Below is the code I am using.

Empty data frame to store the query results

```
# Empty data frame to store query results
query_results <- data.frame(query_date = as.POSIXct(character()),
                query_type = character(),
                query_records = numeric(),
                query_time = as.POSIXct(character()))
```

Function to run database query

```
dbQueryTimes <- function(num_records){
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  fetch(dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM database_table"), n = num_records)
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  query_results$query_time <- end_time - start_time
}
```

Function to input number of iterations to run and number of records to return in query

```
funct_query_select_all <- function(num_iterations, num_records){
  for (i in 1:num_iterations) {
  dbQueryTimes(num_records)
}}
```

Running the query function

```
funct_query_select_all(5, 10000)
```

Comment: `query_results$query_time <- end_time - start_time` from inside a function is an anti-pattern to sound programming, imho. But it's also your bug. You are assigning a single `numeric` to an **empty** `POSIXt` column instead of trying to append it. I suggest you don't use this code you have here, instead use something like `bench::mark(dbSendQuery(...))` (or the `microbenchmark` package).

Comment: Thank you, bench::mark works well, but I still have the same  issue, adding the results from a loop to a df. 
for (i in 1:10) {
  xyz <- bench::mark(fetch(dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM PROD_DIA.GSC_REVENUE_HISTORY"), n = 1000))
}

Comment: You are overwriting `xyz` each time in the `for` loop. Do you expect R to know you intend to append and do that instead?

Comment: I do not expect R to do anything other than run the code. What I am looking for is assistance from a community to help a non developer become better with coding in R, preferably in a useful way without any negativity

Comment: Okay Ryan. You are overwriting `xyz` each time, that does not seem like a useful thing to do. You can (1) assign to an index in a vector/list: `out <- list(); for (i in 1:10) out[[i]] <- bench::mark(..);`; or (2) use a more canonical R method, `out <- lapply(1:10, function(i) bench::mark(..))`. BTW, since you are repeating the same query, you might want to consider that the DBMS might recognize the query and use a pre-compiled version, in which case the first might be slower than the second and subsequent. It depends on the DBMS and the query (and tables).

Comment: Thank you for this info and the DBMS piece. I planned on running it once, but wanted the option to run it a few times to see if there was any variation based on internet loads, but something to take into consideration. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

here is a minimal example that is something like what you're trying to do:

```
## empty dataframe to store results 
query_results <- data.frame(query_date = as.POSIXct(character()),
                            query_type = character(),
                            query_records = numeric(),
                            query_time = as.POSIXct(character()))
## to make reproducible example
set.seed(4919)

## for 12 new "records"
for(i in 1:12){
  ## new results 
  query_date <- Sys.Date()
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  query_type <- sample(LETTERS, size=1)
  query_records <- sample(0:99, size=1)
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  query_time <- end_time - start_time
  ## row bind results to existing dataframe
  query_results <- rbind(query_results, 
                         data.frame(query_date, query_type, 
                                    query_records, query_time))
}
```

output

```
   query_date query_type query_records        query_time
1  2021-03-22          P            44 3.838539e-05 secs
2  2021-03-22          A            55 2.694130e-05 secs
3  2021-03-22          J            79 3.147125e-05 secs
4  2021-03-22          D            84 2.264977e-05 secs
5  2021-03-22          U            38 2.312660e-05 secs
6  2021-03-22          K            13 2.384186e-05 secs
7  2021-03-22          T            72 2.527237e-05 secs
8  2021-03-22          M            55 2.479553e-05 secs
9  2021-03-22          N             9 2.527237e-05 secs
10 2021-03-22          X            64 2.598763e-05 secs
11 2021-03-22          B            91 2.574921e-05 secs
12 2021-03-22          Y            65 2.503395e-05 secs
```

there are likely more elegant ways to solve this problem, but the loop above makes a single row then `rbind`s that row to the existing dataframe. as pointed out in the comments, the way you added a single element in your example doesn't work.